# Окно копирования файлов из NSE

Tags: c++, windows, explorer

Во время копирования файлов проводник показывает стандартное окно копирования. Оно реализовано в стандартном компоненте, имеющим `CLSID_ProgressDialog` и интерфейс `IProgressDialog`. Начиная с Windows Vista, появился новый стандартный диалог копирования, который поддержан тем же компонентом, но имеет другой интерфейс: `IOperationsProgressDialog`. При создании компонента диалог копирования будет иметь вид, зависящий от того, с каким интерфейсом его создали: `IProgressDialog` - "старый" диалог, `IOperationsProgressDialog` - "новый" диалог.

Я разработал namespace extension под Windows 7. Если "тянуть" с него файлы в проводник, то выполняется следующая последовательность действий:

1. `IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf` -> проводник получает `IDataObject` копируемых данных
2. `IDataObject::GetData` -> данные представлены форматами клипборда: `FILEDESCRIPTOR, FILECONTENTS`
3. `FILECONTENTS` -> проводник из формата `FILECONTENTS` получает `IStream`, из которого можно читать данные файлов
4. `IStream::Read` -> непосредственное чтение.

В структуре `FILEDESCRIPTOR` можно указать, что нужно показывать диалог копирования (`FD_PROGRESSUI`). Диалог показывается, но это "старый" диалог. Как его сделать "новым", не понятно. Я (NSE) его не рисую, не создаю, не управляю процессом копирования. Как проводнику дать понять, что нужно использовать "новый" диалог? А то при копировании из проводника в проводник диалог копирования "новый", а при копировании с моего NSE в проводник - "старый".